# Attempting to return a number that represents the number of books that are currently checked out of the library

Tags: javascript

This is the prompt:

"The `getBooksBorrowedCount()` function in `public/src/home.js` has a single parameter:

- An array of books.

It returns a number that represents the number of books *that are currently checked out of the library.* This number can be found by looking at the first transaction in the `borrows` key of each book. If the transaction says the book has not been returned (i.e. `returned: false`), the book has been borrowed."

What I have tried:

```
function getBooksBorrowedCount(books){                                                      
  for (let i = 0; i < books.length; i++) {
    if (books[i].returned === true) {
        return books[i];
    }
}
return null;                                                                                  
}
```

Every time I run this code I receive an error stating that "expected null to equal 6" for the life of me i cannot figure this out, I need some help.

Example Data is listed here:

```
const books = [{id: "5f447132d487bd81da01e25e",
               title: "sit eiusmod occaecat eu magna",
               genre: "Science",
               authorId: 8,
               borrows: [
  {
    id: "5f446f2e2cfa3e1d234679b9",
    returned: false,
  },
  {
    id: "5f446f2ed3609b719568a415",
    returned: true,
  },
  {
    id: "5f446f2e1c71888e2233621e",
    returned: true,
  },
  {
    id: "5f446f2e6059326d9feb9a68",
    returned: true,
  },
  {
    id: "5f446f2ede05a0b1e3394d8b",
    returned: true,
  },
  {
    id: "5f446f2e4081699cdc6a2735",
    returned: true,
  },
  {
    id: "5f446f2e3900dfec59489477",
    returned: true,
  },
  {
    id: "5f446f2e6059326d9feb9a68",
    returned: true,
  },
  {
    id: "5f446f2e409f8883af2955dd",
    returned: true,
  },
  {
    id: "5f446f2e3900dfec59489477",
    returned: true,
  },
  {
    id: "5f446f2eae901a82e0259947",
    returned: true,
  },
  {
    id: "5f446f2ef2ab5f5a9f60c4f2",
    returned: true,
  },
  {
    id: "5f446f2ea6b68cf6f85f6e28",
    returned: true,
  },
```

Comment: **Java is *not* JavaScript**. Don't confuse them. I've removed the [tag:java] tag.

Comment: You want the count, but you return when you find a book that is returned? `return books[i];`???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to access the first `borrows` array item to get your data

```js
const books = [{
  id: "5f447132d487bd81da01e25e",
  title: "sit eiusmod occaecat eu magna",
  genre: "Science",
  authorId: 8,
  borrows: [{
      id: "5f446f2e2cfa3e1d234679b9",
      returned: false,
    },
    {
      id: "5f446f2ed3609b719568a415",
      returned: true,
    },
    {
      id: "5f446f2e1c71888e2233621e",
      returned: true,
    },
    {
      id: "5f446f2e6059326d9feb9a68",
      returned: true,
    },
    {
      id: "5f446f2ede05a0b1e3394d8b",
      returned: true,
    },
    {
      id: "5f446f2e4081699cdc6a2735",
      returned: true,
    },
    {
      id: "5f446f2e3900dfec59489477",
      returned: true,
    },
    {
      id: "5f446f2e6059326d9feb9a68",
      returned: true,
    },
    {
      id: "5f446f2e409f8883af2955dd",
      returned: true,
    },
    {
      id: "5f446f2e3900dfec59489477",
      returned: true,
    },
    {
      id: "5f446f2eae901a82e0259947",
      returned: true,
    },
    {
      id: "5f446f2ef2ab5f5a9f60c4f2",
      returned: true,
    },
    {
      id: "5f446f2ea6b68cf6f85f6e28",
      returned: true,
    }
  ]
}]

function getBooksBorrowedCount(books) {
let count = 0
  for (let i = 0; i < books.length; i++) {
    if (books[i].borrows[0].returned !== true) count++
  }
  return count;
}

console.log(getBooksBorrowedCount(books))
//Another way of doing this with less code:

let numBooksBorrowed = 0;
books.forEach(book => {
  if (!book.borrows[0].returned) numBooksBorrowed++;
});

console.log(numBooksBorrowed)
```

Comment: If i use the .borrow[0] it returns error with full object: "expected { Object (id, title, ...) } to equal 6"

Comment: @PelicanMan5 - I updated my answer (and the code) to use your original array, and show the results from the 2 different ways of getting the count. I don't understand that error you're getting. Pls try with this revised code and let meknow. Thx

Comment: That one worked! I was so close to that solution too! Thanks for your help @Kinglish